# Why does my php/crontab script not save files where I intend?

Tags: php, macos, terminal, cron

I'm new to using crontab and I would like to save an xml file every X minutes. The php and crontab scripts I'm using work fine (now), except I can't get the fetched files to save where I want `~/Desktop/cron-test`. What am I doing wrong? Right now, it's saving all the files to `~/`

My code (in the `cron-test` folder) is

```
<?php
// Download an xml feed and save it as a new file in a directory

$url = 'http://myfeed/api/rss/options';

function download_feed($url) {
  date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
  $date = date('n-j-Y-gi-a');

  // I've tried other paths including
  // ./my-file, ~/Desktop/cron-test/my-file

  $filename = 'my-file' . '-' . $date;
  $xml = file_get_contents($url);

  file_put_contents($filename, $xml);
}

download_feed($url);
```

The cronjob I wrote is `* * * * * /usr/bin/php ~/Desktop/cron-test/xml-download.php`

Comment: there are syntax errors in the code above

Comment: Try using an absolute pathname.

Comment: Fix the syntax error (missing quote) and use an absolute pathname as suggested above. Don't use `~` on your code, because `~` resolves to the home folder of the current user, you can't always be sure that your user is running the script (Or you can, if you're sure about what you're doing)

Comment: `__DIR__` would be a good choice in this case as you want the file in the same directory as the script

Comment: `__DIR__` is working. Sorry about the missing quote.